# Is there any (known) way to have Arxiv waive the endorsement requirement?

Tags: arxiv, independent-researcher

I’m trying to submit a preprint of my paper to the Arxiv as an independent researcher. My academic background is in theoretical physics; I have a PhD in physics, did a postdoc, published several papers in Physical Review and PRL before taking a job in industry. I’ve been working in industry ever since, so I do not currently have an affiliation (i.e. an `.edu` email). I’ve spent the past few years working on my research project independently, and I’d like to submit to the Arxiv and have the community review my results.

I’m currently stuck at the “not endorsed” step. I’ve reached out to qualified endorsers in my subject per the Arxiv’s endorsement process but got no replies. I then contacted the moderation to appeal, but they rejected with what seems like a template reply (“We insist submitters be affiliated...”)

Given my situation, I am wondering if there is any known way to make the Arxiv waive the requirement of endorsement? For example, does the Arxiv make an exception for former academic researchers who have previous publications in peer-reviewed journals?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55624/discussion-on-question-by-mikevon-is-there-any-known-way-to-have-arxiv-waive-t).

Answer (score 6):

1. Just to check, your first request for endorsement emails were hopefully to your thesis advisor/postdoc advisor. If they haven't gotten back to you, either you definitely haven't waited long enough or there may be some other issue (they don't want you to submit to arxiv without them looking at it first?).
2. Worth looking to see if there are other ways to get a .edu address. If you are a researcher in a relevant industry, you could potentially get some degree of honorary affiliation with a local university just by asking the right people. However, this is probably much harder than getting an endorser! You should also look into your PhD and undergraduate school's policies: many offer "alumni" email addresses that are .edu - but I'm not sure if this is sufficient for arxiv's purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you reach out to several more qualified endorsers – perhaps waiting a few days before contacting the next. There are many reasons why the one endorser you contacted already may not have replied. Maybe they're busy, sick, or on holiday. Do you know any old supervisors or collaborators that are endorsers? They might be much more likely to help out!

There is no officially documented way to circumvent the endorsement process, though I would argue that you do have the right to have your work endorsed within a reasonable period of time. Otherwise, clearly the endorsement process is broken. Endorsers should not be endorsers if they don't have the time to endorse!

If you have no success after contacting at least several more endorsers, you could try [contacting the moderation team](https://arxiv.org/help/contact).

Comment: "Endorsers should not be endorsers if they don't have the time to endorse!" I disagree. Being an endorser means having submitted a large enough number of papers on the arXiv in the last 5 years. That does not make you have any greater obligation to respond quickly to endorsement requests.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft "Being an endorser means having submitted a large enough number of papers on the arXiv in the last 5 years." I disagree: The latter (i.e. "having submitted a large enough number of papers on the arXiv in the last 5 years.") means that submitter has been actively submitting papers to arXiv. The former (i.e. "Being an endorser") means, by definition, someone who can/could/would/will endorse a quality paper. I absolutely disagree with you stating the former "means" the latter.

Comment: I agree with @Moriarty; arXiv should only mark authors as "qualified endorser" IFF they are _actually_ willing to expend time endorsing. Otherwise, it's a complete waste of time for all parties. Also, it's completely misleading for the submitter to think that contacting said "endorser" has even a possible chance of getting an endorsement from him/her.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft "That does not make you have any greater obligation to respond quickly to endorsement requests."

This discussion/answer is not about "responding quickly"; it's about responding at all.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was unaware that the status of "endorser" is an automatic thing based on your number of submissions. This is likely why it's difficult to get a reply – you can be sending endorsement requests to people who are not going to read them. Clearly, this is not an optimal situation...

Comment: I agree that it might be more optimal with a system in which one could more easily find people who had actively chosen to be endorsers rather than just having submitted papers (probably a lot of people are endorsers without being aware that this is even a thing).